# C++. std::condition_variable and multiple wait-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, std

I have some class, with `queue` of `std::function<void()>` member and  methods `Push` and `Pop`.

I want to implement addition method `PushAndWaitUntilExecuted`. It is easy when you have one `consumer-thread`(who call `Pop`) and one `producer-thread`(who call `Push`) - just simple `std::condition_variable` will be enough.

But my application have dynamic number of threads which can execute the same lines of code with calling  `PushAndWaitUntilExecuted` function in parallel and wait until `consumer-thread` execute pushed `std::function` object.

A have the idea with passing `std::pair<uint64_t, std::function<void()>>` to `queue` instead of just `std::function<void()>`, where `uint64_t` - `producer-thread ID`(`boost::this_thread::get_id()`). And then `consumer-thread` call `std::condition_variable::notify_all()` and all threads will check if executed `std::function` have same `ID` with thread or not.

Is it ok solution or something better can be implemented?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use multiple conditional variables and store them together with function objects? Then, any thread could wait only for a specific function (and not be waked when other functions are executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than just a condition variable needs to be introduced here, in order to avoid several different race conditions. A mutex and a job completion flag are also required.

At this point, it becomes cleaner to replace your `std::function<void()>` with a small class that contains this closure, as well as all the additional baggage:

```
struct job {
   std::function<void()> implementation;
   std::mutex m;
   std::condition_variable flag;
   bool completed=false;
};
```

Your queue becomes a queue of `std::shared_ptr<job>`s, instead of a queue of `std::function`s, with the jobs constructed in dynamic scope (since, of course, mutexes and condition variables are not copyable or movable, and these objects get accessed from both of your threads).

After your worker thread finishes executing the *implementation*, it:

1. locks the mutex.
2. sets `completed` to true
3. signals the condition variable.

And your `PushAndWaitUntilExecuted`, after it executes the push:

1. locks the mutex
2. waits on the condition variable, until `completed` is set

You must thoroughly understand that C++ gives you absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that after you push a new closure into your job queue, some thread doesn't immediately grab it, execute it, and finish it, before the original thread (the one that pushed it) gets around to looking at the condition variable. By now, nobody will be signaling the condition variable any more. If all you have to work with is just a condition variable here, you'll be waiting for the condition variable to get signaled until our sun explodes.

Which is why you need more than just a condition variable, a mutex and an explicit flag, and use the above approach, to correctly handle interthread sequencing.

This is a fairly classical, routine approach. You should find examples of many similar implementations in every good C++ textbook on this subject matter.